# Jqgrid, additional white space when vertical scrolling is enabled

Tags: javascript, html, jqgrid

I have an issue with my grid, after loading data and enabling vertical scroll, i find my grid loaded with additional space after the my rows. I want that removed, any idea why i am getting this ?

This is my grid with the scroll bar
[image: My grid]

This is the problem
[image]

I just want the scroll bar to stop at number 20, i don't want all that additional space.

And this is my grid setting :

```
$html .=        '$("#'. $this->_name .'").jqGrid({';
        $html .=            'url:"tools/grid_server_calls.php",';
        $html .=            'datatype: "json",';
        $html .=            'autoencode: true,';
        $html .=            'mtype: "POST",';
        $html .=            'postData:{inputs:'. $this->_server_inputs .'},';
        $html .=            'gridview: true,';
        $html .=            'ignoreCase: true,';
        //$html .=          'loadui: "block",';

        $html .=            'hidegrid: false,';

        $html .=            'width: "' . $this->_width_grid . 'px",';
        $html .=            'forceFit: true,';
        $html .=            'pager: "#pager_'.$this->_name.'",';
        $html .=            'rowNum: ' . $this->_rowNum . ',';
        $html .=            'rowList: [' . $this->_rowList . '],';

        if( $this->_scroll_enabled ){
                $html .=            'scroll: true,';
                $html .=            'height: "230px",';
        }
        else{
            $html .=            'height: "auto",';
        }

        $html .=            'viewrecords: true,';
        $html .=            'emptyrecords:"'.$this->_message_no_records.'",';
        $html .=            'recordtext:"{0} - {1} / {2}",';
        $html .=            'altRows: true,';
        $html .=            'multiselect: "' . $this->_multiselect .'",';
        $html .=            'altclass: "color_line_grid",';
        $html .=            'caption: "' . $this->_caption . '",';
        $html .=            'colNames: [' . $this->_colNames . '],';
        $html .=            'colModel: [' . $this->_colModel . '],';
        $html .=            'sortname: "' . $this->_initialSort . '",';
        $html .=            'sortorder: "asc",';

        if(!$this->_search_enabled){
            $html .=            'pgbuttons: false,';
            $html .=            'pgtext: null,';
            $html .=            'rowList: [],';
            $html .=            'cmTemplate: {sortable:false},';
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to the root of the problem, it was as simple as learning to read before asking dumb questions, in fact you need not set scroll to true, you just need to set a height, when the data exceeds the height that was set, the scroll bar will appear automatically 'In my case' .